# Windows 10, Blender cannot open write save on C:

Tags: windows, installation

I just noticed this recently, I cannot save my blend file.  Cannot open file for writing permission denied.

I have been using Blender for over 5 years and installed it multiple times on multiple computers.  I cannot save on C: drive all of a sudden and I have went into properties on the drive and allowed all permissions.

I can only use blender now as an administrator which is annoying and ridiculous.  I am using windows 10 which it never used to do this before.

All of a sudden, an update or security setting may have done this but I have tried everything--forums, youtube, etc. and nothing fixes this problem.

I know I am not the only one to be having this problem via forums.

This may not be a Blender issue directly but I think your team should look into why this is occurring on multiple computers, I have 3, all around the same time frame-within a week.

This is a Blender windows 10 issue.  I have uninstalled the program, files, and downloaded the installer - like I have multiple times in multiple years - and installed it the same way from the website and it does not fix the problem.

Only Blender is affected - no other programs that I have, photoshop, gimp, paint, etc. ...   Please look into this and thank you.

Matt Mathers

Comment: *Not an answer*. personal info has been edited out of the post. Please read https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/should-a-question-be-allowed-to-contain-contact-details/2394#2394

Comment: from here it seem some installation issue (if you recently updated), or some weird operating system issue (win 10 recent updates?) or maybe a workgroup shared folder permission issue...  also, why did you set "texturing" tag for this...?!?

Comment: This has been asked before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84602/cannot-save-blend-files-permission-denied

Comment: Are you are trying to save in the root directory of C:  with a standard user account?  The standard user does not have rights to the root of C: only the administrator account does. Configure blender to save to a directory that the user has access to. This is not an issue with blender, but how your operating system works